# 2 pass effect in opengl

Tags: opengl, shader, fbo

I try to create a 2 pass effect using FBO in OpenGL.

In the first pass, I write the depth in a color buffer (image 1):

[image]

Using the following in its vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * gl_Vertex;
vec4 position = gl_Position/gl_Position.w;
position = position / 2.0 + 0.5;
float temp_depth = position.z;
gl_FrontColor = vec4(temp_depth,temp_depth,temp_depth,1);
```

In the second pass I try to use the texture from the previous pass and color the scene (image 2):

[image]

Here is the code in vertex shader:

```
vec4 shadow_coord  = projection * view * gl_Vertex;
shadow_coord = shadow_coord / shadow_coord.w;
shadow_coord = shadow_coord / 2.0 + 0.5;
gl_FrontColor  = texture2D(light_depth_texture, shadow_coord.xy);
```

The scene is consisted of a quad in the front of a cone.  In both cases the fragment shader is `gl_FragColor = gl_Color;` The view and projection matrices in both cases are exactly the same defined at start.  The problems is that there is a deviation in shadow_coord.xy.

As long as the view and projection values are exactly the same, shouldn't I get same result?

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Comment: Did you use Float texture for depth buffer?

Comment: Hello.

I dont write to depth buffer. I write to color buffer.
Internal format:GL_RGBA
Source format: GL_RGBA
type: GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE

Thnx

Comment: @getpfault i use #version 120

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but it seems odd to store a depth value using only 8 bit precision.

Answer (score 0):

What resolution do you use for the texture you render into? And what kind of filtering? (seems linear, should be nearest). Also try to offset the coordinate you read with like:

```
// offset should be 0.5 / texture_resolution
gl_FrontColor  = texture2D(light_depth_texture, shadow_coord.xy + offset);
```

And as the other commenters mentioned, 8 bit is not enough to store depth values, consider using a depth texture or a floating point format (like GL_R32F as in [ARB_texture_rg](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_rg.txt)).